# Theme Integration Problem Frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, frontend, html

When I Integrate HTML Theme Magento 1.9
For Learning Purpose, I Use Static Blocks For Display Some Content In Frontend,
but All Content Are Not Display Properly.
it was shown in middle.

pls help me,

[image]

**Original Image is that Here. Can See The Difference Between Both
Images..**

[image]

Comment: Header and Footer are Complete Display, But Main Content Display as Middle, Not Display Like Header-Footer

Comment: Wich content are you talking about ?

Comment: all middle content

Comment: I can't see the problem in your image, the middle is the content of your page its normal. Look your theme settings, you will find some config

Comment: you can see the difference between Carousel. that not set properly.